# Google Guice: right way to inject primitive data structure

Tags: java, guice

```
private HashSet<WorkWindow> childWorkWindows;

@Inject
public CompositeWorkWindows (
        HashSet childWorkWindows
) {
    this.childWorkWindows = childWorkWindows;
}
```

Would Guice know how to inject this automatically without having to specify anything in the module?

My concern is that i am specifying the type for HashSet in the private field.

Comment: A binding or provider has to be created so it knows where/how to get the set

Comment: @MatthewKerian so in constructor it is okay to be left as HashSet childWorkWindows, instead of HashSet<WorkWindow> childWorkWindows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You must first bind it

In your configuration:

```
@Provides HashSet<WorkWindow> provideChildWorkWindows() {
  // Create and return your HashSet<WorkWindow>
}
```

Then only it will be injectable in your `CompositeWorkWindows`.

If you want to bind several, independant `WorkWindow`, use Guice's multibinding. But in that case, you should use the interface `Set` as recipient, instead of the `HashSet` implementation, because Guice will provide a `Set` but not a `HashSet`. Note that multibinding allows you to have the definitions of the elements in different modules.

In **`MyModule.java`**:

```
Multibinder<WorkWindow> workWindowBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), WorkWindow.class);
workWindowBinder.addBinding().toInstance(new MyWorkWindow());
```

In **`OtherModule.java`**:

```
Multibinder<WorkWindow> workWindowBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), WorkWindow.class);
workWindowBinder.addBinding().to(OtherWorkWindow.class);
```

In **`FinalModule.java`**:

```
Multibinder<WorkWindow> workWindowBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), WorkWindow.class);
workWindowBinder.addBinding().toProvider(new FinalWorkWindowProvider());
```

If all modules are present in an injector, you will get a `Set` that has a size of 3, containing the three different `WorkWindow` you created.

Comment: so this is needed even if i want to return "new Hashset<>()"? datafilling the hashset happens else where. i just want it to instantiate a generic hashset. Provider is needed even for that?

Comment: @ealeon Yeah, in your provider you'd just do return new HashSet or whatever. You can also do it on a global basis, if for example every hash set returns a new hash set, you can bind the hash set class to the provider that returns a new hash set, then you only need to bind that once.

Comment: @ealeon I've updated the answer with how you can "datafill" the set in several places rather than in one single place.